# How do I insert Unique random integers into a linked list?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've been trying to figure out how to insert 50 unique random integers ranging from 1 to 100. I looked at other examples, but it's been difficult to translate into the code I'm using. Could someone put me in the right direction without changing the code I have too much, please?

```
void displayListForward(SortedListInterface<int>* listPtr)
{
cout << "The sorted list contains " << endl;
for (int pos = 1; pos <= listPtr->getLength(); pos++)
{
    cout << listPtr->getEntry(pos) << " ";
}
cout << endl << endl;
}  


void InsertRandomInts() 
{
LinkedSortedList<int> list;
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) 
{
    int b = rand() % 100 + 1;
    list.insertSorted(b);
    displayListForward(&list);
}
}
```

Comment: Start with a [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), insert as long as its size is less than the requested number of values, then copy over to the list.

Comment: I don't understand set. I'm already keeping my values less then the number I want.

Comment: Then what is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem you're having making them unique? If so, you could add a helper function to search the existing list , and add the number if it doesn't exist, or generate a new one if it does. It may also be easier to create the numbers in another data structure and then initialise them in the linked list as you create the nodes.

You could use a search function like this, and a condition inside your InsertRandomInts function to determine if its unique:

```
bool search(std::vector<std::int> list, int obj){
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        // key already exists in list
        if (obj == list[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    // not found
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How would I put that into InsertRandomInts? Something like declaring a bool called Exists and then saying search() If(Exists=true) remove(i)? I don't know what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, C++ have much better [pseudo-random generation utilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) than the old C `srand` and `rand` functions.

Secondly, [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (and better yet for this case, [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)) are very nice to get a collection of unique values.

It can be used as

```
std::random_device r;
std::default_random_engine e1(r());

// To get random numbers between 1 and 100 (inclusive)
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 100);

// A set to store values
std::unordered_set<int> random_values;

// Loop until we get 50 unique random values
while (random_values.size() < 50)
{
    random_values.insert(uniform_dist(e1));
}

// Now there are 50 unique (pseudo) random numbers in the set
```

Comment: STDs not taking random_device r or default_random_engine. It says they're not members.

Comment: @KennethDionisi Then either you're not including the correct headers, or your compiler is old and need special flags to enable C++11 functionality (or to old to have it at all, in which case you should upgrade).

Comment: @KennethDionisi Please follow the links to a reference, and look around. You should easily find out what headers are needed.